# LINQ expression to replace foreach with multiple awaits

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I am trying to determine if there is a linq expression equivalent of the following foreach statement below?

Two of the several solutions I've tried are commented with their results below the loop.  I thought the first example or a variation would work but the type is always IEnumerable<Task> unless I call it synchronously which just feels apprehensive.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanySettings>> GetClientSettingsAsync()
{
    foreach(var company in await GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync())
    {
        settings.Add(new CompanySettings(company, await GetSyncDataAsync(company)));
    }

    // a's Type is IEnumerable<Task<CompanySetting>> and not IEnumerable<CompanySetting>
    // var a = (await GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync())
    //     .Select(async x => new CompanySettings(x, await GetSyncDataAsync(x)));
    // return a;


    // b's Type is correct it's also synchronous.  Does that matter?
    // var b = (GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync()).Result
    //    .Select(x => new CompanySettings(x, GetSyncDataAsync(x).Result));
    //return b;

    return settings;
}
```

Signatures of the methods:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<UpdoxCompany>> GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync();
private async Task<UpdoxSyncData> GetUpdoxSyncDataAsync(UpdoxCompany company);
```

Comment: Could you include the signature of the methods `GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync` and `GetSyncDataAsync`?

Comment: private async Task<IEnumerable<UpdoxCompany>> GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync()
private async Task<UpdoxSyncData> GetUpdoxSyncDataAsync(UpdoxCompany company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close with your first attempt, you just need to await the tasks that are returned

```
async Task<IEnumerable<CompanySettings>> GetClientSettingsAsync() {

    var companies = await GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync();
    var companySettings = companies.Select(async company =>
        new CompanySettings(company, await GetSyncDataAsync(company))
    );

    return await Task.WhenAll(companySettings);
}
```

Comment: It was the Task.WhenAll in order to materialize the CompanySettings that I was missing!  Thank you!  I was able to reduce this down to a bodiless method.

Comment: @jrandomuser in your question you are asking for an equivalent LINQ expression. This answer contains code with non-equivalent behavior, so you should probably edit and clarify the question.

Comment: My apologies sir you are correct in that it isn't the actual linq expression (from x in y select x etc)  I was looking for the method of using linq through the extension methods, but I wasn't sure what exactly you call that syntax?  Linq Extension Method syntax?  I appreciate your feedback, it will help me to be more clear.

Comment: @jrandomuser I believe you are talking about the _method syntax in LINQ_. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) is a Microsoft article about LINQ query syntax and method syntax that may be of interest.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use Select to achieve the same result

Here is one way to do it:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CompanySettings>> GetClientSettingsAsync()
{
    var companies = await GetParticipatingCompaniesAsync();
    var companySettingsTasks = companies.Select(async company => 
        new CompanySettings(company, await GetSyncDataAsync(company)));
    var settings = await Task.WhenAll(companySettingsTasks);
    return settings;
}
```